# Short tailed/Long tailed distributions and their effects on p-value interpretation when assuming normality

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, p-value, normality-assumption, heavy-tailed

Can anyone offer better insight into the comparison of how p-values for hypothesis tests are affected when your distribution is short/long tailed but we assume it is normally distributed?  I'm specifically wondering about this with respect to the usual regression diagnostics (QQ-Plot to affecting t-test, F-test, etc)

I seem to recall a short-tailed distribution inflates p-values when assuming normality, so statistically significant p-values are still significant but we can possibly miss actually-significant results.  A long-tailed distribution is the opposite, deflating p-values and running a greater risk of claiming significance on false-positives.

Any greater insight or literature detailing this behavior would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussing this topic for regression will be difficult without more details.
Are you asking about simple linear regression (one predictor variable)?
Is the non-normality evident from looking at residuals, or is non-normality suspected for some other reason?

Here is a brief discussion, based on simulation in R, for two-sample Welch t tests, using normal, uniform (no tails), and exponential (heavy right tails) as examples. I hope some of the issues of interest to you will be addressed by looking at results for t tests.

**Significance level.** With any test, intended to be at the 5% level of significance, it is a good idea
to check whether the actual significance level is nearly 5%. So here are results
of three simulations in which sample sizes are $n_1=n_2=10$ and the two samples
come from exactly the same distribution. I use very small sample sizes because
the rubustness of the t test against nonnormal data tends to improve for larger $n.$
(All three populations have $\sigma \approx 1.)$

```
## Null Hypothesis True:  Actual Signif Levels

set.seed(628)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,0,1),rnorm(10,0,1))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04845

set.seed(629)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(runif(10,0,3.464),runif(10,0,3.464))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04993

set.seed(630)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(10,1),rexp(10,1))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.03653
```

Results for normal and uniform data show significance levels that essentially
match 5% within simulation error. It is no surprise that uniform data performs
well because means of samples of size 10 from a uniform distribution are
hard to distinguish from normal.

**Power.** If we test a normal sample of size 10 from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ against
a sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(1,1),$ which is a shift of one unit, then the power
(probability of rejecting $H_0)$ is about $0.884 = 88.4\%.$ Power against a rightward shift of 1 unit for uniform data is about the same. Also for exponential data the power is about the same.

```
## Null Hypothesis False: Power against shift to right of 1.5

set.seed(628)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,0,1),rnorm(10,0,1)+1.5)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.88406

set.seed(629)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(runif(10,0,3.464),runif(10,0,3.464)+1.5)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.89382

set.seed(630)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(10,1),rexp(10,1)+1.5)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.87095
```

Overall, rejection levels may be a little lower for exponential data because
the t statistic may not have exactly Student's t distribution. (I have used Welch
two-sample t tests, which do not assume equal variances, so in instances where
long right tails of exponential sample give unusually large sample variances
the Welch t test may perform better than the pooled test.)

**Detecting non-normality.** With sample sizes as small as 10, detecting non-normality can be difficult. Normal probability plots and Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality are shown below for small normal,
uniform, and exponential samples.

[image]

```
set.seed(1234)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 x1 = rnorm(10)
  qqnorm(x1, main="Normal");  qqline(x1)
 x2 = runif(10,0,3.464)
  qqnorm(x2, main="Uniform"); qqline(x2)
 x3 = rexp(10,1)
  qqnorm(x3, main="Exponential"); qqline(x3)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

shapiro.test(x1)$p.val; shapiro.test(x2)$p.val; shapiro.test(x3)$p.val
[1] 0.7294606
[1] 0.1470564
[1] 0.3675874
```

**Possible availability of better test than t.** As a practical matter it is worth mentioning that t tests are by far not the
best tests for uniform data: any sample with a value above 4.565 is just by
itself reason to reject $H_0.$ For exponential data a complete lack of observations below 1.5 in the second sample provides strong evidence for rejection. (The probability of that would be about $0.0000003.)$ The lesson here is that a good reason for
avoiding a t test may not be that it is a 'little off' for nonnormal data, but rather that a much better test may be available.

```
(1 - pexp(1.5, 1))^10
[1] 3.059023e-07
```